# Finding Rails DB In Sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

So I created a db with '`sqlite development`'. I then ran '`rake db:setup`' and it seemed to execute without error. However when I launch the sqlite console, I can't seem to find any of the tables within the development database. Maybe I'm not accessing the database correctly? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done `rake db:create`? I using that command to create the databases, not manually add the databases.

Comment: I had not, but I actually just did it and have now found the db!

Comment: Did what? the `rake db:create`?

Comment: Haha sorry, yes, rake db:create.

Comment: Ok I'll put it in answer sheet and you can accept that so people know by looking forward on it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done `rake db:create`? I using that command to create the databases, not manually add the databases.

*copied from comment section*